# Audio plays well in iPhone simulator but not in iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, ios-simulator

I have an app that is nearly finished but encountered an annoying problem.  In the app, I want to play a sound when I tap on some object, then the object disappears.  This is the piece of code I used:

In Object.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

@interface Object: UIView {
    UIImageView *image;
    CGPoint location;
    SystemSoundID soundFileID;
}
```

In Object.m

```
- (void)initWithSound {
    //a bunch of code to define the image and location
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound" ofType:@"caf"];
    CFURLRef soundURL = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &soundFileID);
    return self;
}
```

Then in my mainViewController, several objects will be created upon user's action and added to the screen at different locations with different images.  Upon tapping on the object itself, it will create a sound and disappear.

In Object.m

```
- (void)tapped {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundFileID);
    image.image = nil;
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Everything works find in the simulator.  But when I tried that in iPhone, the object disappears on tapping as expected but the sound just doesn't play.  Tried on a 3G and a 3GS, both don't play the sound.  I think this should work.  Am I making any mistakes?  Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Just think of something that I don't know related or not.  I'm also using the microphone to detect sound input from the user by AVAudioRecorder.  Not sure if this would affect the audio output.

Comment: check if your sound file is named "Sound.caf" and not "sound.caf" - file system on iPhone is case sensitive and in MacOS is not - it often causes such kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Vladimir.  Checked the file name is correct.

Comment: A simple thing to check is to comment out `[self removeFromSuperview];` just to see if the sound will play by itself without adding in removing the button from the view.  It's sometimes easier to "chunk" your debugging to find which part is causing the issue.  If the sound plays fine, then you know it's the removal part that is causing a error.  I don't know why, but it might be possible that removing it from the view is cancelling the action so you may have to delay removal or hide it first and upon audio finish you can remove the hidden object.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  Just tried to comment out the removeFromSuperview line, but the sound still doesn't play.  Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found where the problem is!!

It turns out that I have to I have to set up an audio session.  It's just that!  Obviously I need more study on the audio and video things.

Just for someone who may run into the same situation as me, here is the code I added in the viewDidLoad method:

```
AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &error];

[audioSession setActive:YES error: &error];
```

Comment: I added AVFoundation and CoreAudio as well.

Comment: Thanks!!  AVAudioSession is in the AVFoundation framework, so make sure you include that in your build.